# Using .join() to create an OL from a form

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, join

I am trying to use .join() to output a message that contains an OL. The code I have below returns the correct message, but I'm wondering if I need a closing OL tag somewhere. The developer tools show the output as a closed OL.

*Note - It must use the join function, please don't recommend using loops, etc.*

```
if (task.value){

    tasks.push(task.value);

    message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol><li>';
    message += tasks.join('</li><li>');
    output.innerHTML = message;
    task.value = '';

}
```

Comment: You can omit the closing `</li>` tag but not `</ol>`, so `message += tasks.join('<li>') + </ol>;` :-)

Comment: Wouldn't this close the list after 1 task is added?

Comment: No. You'll get something like `foo<li>bar</ol>` which results in a full string of `'<h2>To-Do</h2><ol><li>foo<li>bar</ol>'. Closing tag for LI is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to close the `ol` tag somewhere. Although most browsers try to guess and fix the missing tag, sometimes it can't.

You can just concatenate the closing tag after the join line:

```
    message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol><li>';
    message += tasks.join('</li><li>');
    message += '</li></ol>';
    output.innerHTML = message;
```